# Can containment/content indicators come after the outside and inside words?

Tags: cryptic-clues

I have surface I like for a cryptic clue I want to write that is of the form:

> outside-word inside-word indicator

Something like:

Fix railway without cat

> F [EL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_%22L%22) IX

Or

Crafts day about Monday to Friday

> WORK DAY S

If these exact clues don't work, but this formation would work otherwise, please give an example.

Comment: IMHO, these clues do not work, because the literal words in the wordplay don't lead to the action you want. What might work is something like "Fix, railway within, cat"; obviously this surface is subpar, and there would be legitimate debate over whether even this formulation is fair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that if the indicator is one that is actually used in such a way in English, then it's fair to use that way in a clue also. I can't think of too many such with the desired order of ⟨*outside-word*⟩ ⟨*inside-word*⟩ ⟨*indicator*⟩, but…

One is the formulation "emphasis added" (or "italics supplied", "italicization supplied", "boldfacing supplied", "emphasis supplied", etc.). [It's used](//english.stackexchange.com/a/445515) after a quotation that includes an indication of emphasis (like italics) and shows that that indication was supplied by the quoter and was not in the original authority. A cryptic clue that uses such a phrase:

> "Faded (as in jeans) has gone the way of the *dodo*" (emphasis supplied). (10)

> DISTRESSED = DIED (STRESS supplied)

Another is the formulation "⟨*object*⟩ (batteries included)". For example:

> Former physiotherapist (batteries included) (4)

> PAST = PT ([A](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_battery)s included)

And another, thanks to [Deusovi](/u/11876), is "⟨*outside-word*⟩, ⟨*inside-word*⟩ added". (Indeed, there are other words you can use instead of "added"; but the comma is, I think, desirable.) For example (also Deusovi's):

> "Style", he added, "doesn't look very good." (7)

> CLASS, HE added = CLASHES